# option HTML, change default structure of SelectBox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im a little bit new in this world of coding, so for me this looks like easy problem but i cant solve it. Function that give me such of pain is

```js
function _renderOptions() {
  var optionHTML = [];

  $options.each(function(i, itm) {
    var $this = $(this),
      optgroup = $this.parents('optgroup'),
      addlOptClasses = "",
      iconMarkup = "";

    // render optgroups if present in original select
    if (optgroup.length > 0 && $this.prev().length === 0) {
      optionHTML.push('<dt>' + optgroup.attr('label') + '</dt>');
    }

    // if option has a classname add that to custom select as well
    if (itm.className !== "") {
      $(itm.className.split(" ")).each(function() {
        iconMarkup += '<span class="' + this + '"></span>';
      });
    }

    // add selected class to whatever option is currently active
    if (itm.selected && !itm.disabled) {
      _selectedValue = iconMarkup + _truncate($(itm).html());
      addlOptClasses = " " + SELECTED_CLASS;
    }

    // Check for disabled options
    if (itm.disabled) {
      addlOptClasses += " " + DISABLED_CLASS;
    }

    optionHTML.push('<dd class="itm-' + i + ' ' + addlOptClasses + '">' + iconMarkup + itm.innerHTML + '</dd>');
  });

  if ($selectedValue && $selectedValue.get(0) !== null) {
    $selectedValue.html(_selectedValue);
  }

  return optionHTML.join("");
}
```

What I want is if option has a classname, that same class be added in class on `<dd>` and not to create `<span>` and add class there

Comment: Please create a stand-alone Fiddle, it would help.

Comment: optionHTML.push('<dd class="itm-' + i + ' ' + addlOptClasses + ' ' + $(itm).attr("class") + '">' + iconMarkup + itm.innerHTML + '</dd>');

Comment: @artm Post it as answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the class from the item and add it to `dd` element: `optionHTML.push('<dd class="itm-' + i + ' ' + addlOptClasses + ' ' + $(itm).attr("class") + '">' + iconMarkup + itm.innerHTML + '</dd>');`

```js
function _renderOptions() {
  var optionHTML = [];

  $options.each(function(i, itm) {
    var $this = $(this),
      optgroup = $this.parents('optgroup'),
      addlOptClasses = "",
      iconMarkup = "";

    // render optgroups if present in original select
    if (optgroup.length > 0 && $this.prev().length === 0) {
      optionHTML.push('<dt>' + optgroup.attr('label') + '</dt>');
    }

    // if option has a classname add that to custom select as well
    if (itm.className !== "") {
      $(itm.className.split(" ")).each(function() {
        iconMarkup += '<span class="' + this + '"></span>';
      });
    }

    // add selected class to whatever option is currently active
    if (itm.selected && !itm.disabled) {
      _selectedValue = iconMarkup + _truncate($(itm).html());
      addlOptClasses = " " + SELECTED_CLASS;
    }

    // Check for disabled options
    if (itm.disabled) {
      addlOptClasses += " " + DISABLED_CLASS;
    }

    optionHTML.push('<dd class="itm-' + i + ' ' + addlOptClasses + ' ' + $(itm).attr("class") + '">' + iconMarkup + itm.innerHTML + '</dd>');
  });

  if ($selectedValue && $selectedValue.get(0) !== null) {
    $selectedValue.html(_selectedValue);
  }

  return optionHTML.join("");
}
```